# How to reverse a string in pairs

Tags: javascript

If you have a string `'abcdef'`, how would you go about reversing pairs so it would look like `'badcfe'`? If the string has an odd number of characters, leave the last character in place.

I am aware of `x.spilt('').reverse().join('')` to reverse an entire string but couldn’t figure out the above stated.

Comment: You can do with the same solution you mentioned in the question, but the approach of loop should be diffrent. You can take this as [reference](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3ymhkrqn4)

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? If so, did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple for-loop:

```js
function reversePairs(str) {
  let ret = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
    ret += str.substring(i, i+2).split('').reverse().join('');
  }
  return ret;
}

const str = 'abcdef';
console.log(reversePairs(str))
```